# Concatenar columnas por una COMA

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo está tabla

```
|Nombre | ApellidoP | ApellidoM | Edad |
|--------------------------------------|
|Nombre1| ApellidoP1| ApellidoM1| Edad1|
|Nombre2| ApellidoP2| ApellidoM2| Edad2|
|Nombre3| ApellidoP3| ApellidoM3| Edad3|
```

Quiero algo así:

```
Nombre1, ApellidoP1, ApellidoM1, Edad1
Nombre2, ApellidoP2, ApellidoM2, Edad2
Nombre3, ApellidoP3, ApellidoM3, Edad3
```

Pero lo que quiero saber es si existe una forma de no estar escribiendo columna por columna más las comas: **(COLUMNA1 + ','+COLUMNA2 + ','+...)** Evitar esto:

```sql
SELECT Nombre +','+ ApellidoP +','+ ApellidoM +','+ Edad FROM TABLA
```

He intentado con estas dos formas pero no funcionan:

```sql
SELECT (Nombre, ApellidoP, ApellidoM, Edad) + ',' FROM TABLA

DECLARE @columnas AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @columnas = 'Nombre, ApellidoP, ApellidoM, Edad'
SELECT @columnas +',' FROM TABLA
```

Comment: No, básicamente no hay forma de escribir columna por columna. A menos claro que escribas una sentencia dinámica y luego la ejecutes.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han indicado, en principio, no. Pero digo solo en principio, porque básicamente siempre hay otra manera de hacerlo. Aunque lo primero es mostrarte que tengas cuidado con el + por lo siguiente.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.nombres
(Nombre    VARCHAR(100), 
 apellidoP VARCHAR(100), 
 ApellidoM VARCHAR(100), 
 Edad      VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.nombres
(Nombre, apellidoP, ApellidoM, Edad)
VALUES
('Nombre1','ApellidoP1','ApellidoM1','Edad1'),
('Nombre2','ApellidoP2','ApellidoM2','Edad2'),
('Nombre3','ApellidoP3','ApellidoM3','Edad3');
GO
```

Hasta aquí es tú escenario. Ahora voy a insertar una nueva fila.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.nombres
(Nombre, apellidoP, ApellidoM, Edad)
VALUES
('Nombre4',NULL,'ApellidoM1','Edad1');
```

Esto si aplico el + para concatenar columnas devuelve.

```
SELECT
Nombre + ','+apellidoP+','+ ApellidoM +','+ Edad
FROM dbo.nombres
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Y ese resultado no es el esperado. Pero puedes utilizar la función CONCAT

```
SELECT
CONCAT(Nombre,',',apellidoP,',',ApellidoM,',',Edad)
FROM dbo.nombres
```

La utilización apenas difiere, pero el resultado es completamente diferente.

[image: Resultado 2]

Aunque esto no resuelve tú problema de escribir poco.
Aquí tienes varías alternativas. Te voy a dar una con el Sql Server Management Studio (aunque existen otros complementos que te facilitan esta labor).

Cuando tienes la tabla en el citado gestor, solo tienes que abrir en el explorador de objetos la definición de la tabla y cuando ves la carpeta columnas, realizas click, y arrastras la misma, a la posición que necesites de la ventana del editor, donde estás desarrollando el código, y el gestor, te copia los nombres de todas las columnas de la tabla, de manera que ya tienes una parte importante realizada.

[image: Carpeta Columnas]

[image: Resultado]